# login with admin and guest

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, authentication

ok i have my GUI installed on the server which has users as administrator as the role of an administrators and user1 which has the role of the guest...

I have one project and there are different pages for administrators and guests... when the login screen comes up and the administrator logs in he should be redirected to the admin.aspx page and for user1 he should be redirected to the guest.aspx page.

Now the scenario is i have 10 users in a company and one administrator. This GUI is on the network server and these 10 users are able to access it as guests.

How do the guest user logs in and can access the SQl database in the read only mode but when the administrator user logs in he can access the database in the read and write mode.?? I dont know how to do this really... any suggestions

(by IIS server or webconfig or some setting in SQL server)

and the previous question is what to use (forms or windows authentication) where can i get information on how to set up this kind of authentication???? Is there the need to use impersonation also??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't directly answering your question, but unless you are letting your users (and administrators) write their own queries (which you should never do BTW!) it shouldn't matter.

Users should only have access to options that allow them to read data from the database, not update that data. If they do then it's bad UI design.

You should make sure that the account that "Users" use only has read access - do this from Management Studio. Connect to you server and expand **Security > Logins** in the Object Explorer. Right click and select **New Login...** fill out the form - select "SQL Server authentication". You can then grant and deny access to the relevant parts of your database. Check the SQL Server documentation for more details.

Comment: hi.. thanks.. the database security works fine... can u give any suggestions on how to solve my other problem of redirecting to different pages for admin and guests... and what to use windows or forms authentication>>>??

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say your GUI is installed...?

This might be something that's tied into your CODE (if guest then don't allow writes, etc).

You might use two different accounts for DB access depending on the user if you'd like to.

Comment: gui installed means that i have published the gui and is stored in the inetpub folder of the server...